# Paypal Sandbox - Transaction history show fixed amount

Tags: paypal

Hi I'm new to Paypal integration.

I have successfully setup Express Checkout in my online shop.

But in my Sandbox account, the balance is always reduced by 20$ for every transaction no matter how much the real value is.

For example I have an item that costs 35$. During checkout process, it does say "35$". But when logging into the sandbox account, It says "**-20$**" in the transaction history.

Does sandbox works like that? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're sending $35.00 in the SetExpressCheckout request but then your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request is sending 20.00.

Comment: Oops what a silly mistake. I used CakePHP plugin and the example set the doExpressCheckout to 20.00